# NVDA screen-reader reads url from href after clicking an anchor tag in Firefox

Tags: firefox, accessibility, nvda

I have this item on a page `<a role="option" href="[looong url]">My Item</a>`

After clicking on this item in Firefox in **regular mode** NVDA reads:

> document busy
>
> [looong url from browser's address bar]
>
> application
>
> My Item

When I click on the item again it doesn't read the url (**desired behavior**):

> document busy
>
> blank
>
> application
>
> My Item

In the meantime when I do the same thing in Firefox in **private mode** it reads every time as expected:

> document busy
>
> blank
>
> application
>
> My Item

Is that an expected difference in FF behavior for regular and private modes?

Comment: Folks, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per NVDA developers forum it is a Firefox issue related to browser's inconsistency in *private* and *regular* mode while reading the same page by a screen-reader.

https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/6573

Thus the question might be closed.